# Frequency of update of term store

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-store

I do operations such as move term from one parent term to another or rename term.

Is there a stated update frequency (when the renamed term actually appears or when the moved term actually looks under the right parent term)? I have noticed it is random, from 30 min to more than a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a hidden list called TaxonomyHiddenList on each site collection in SharePoint that caches the terms used in that site collection. It takes time to update. The hidden list can be found on any site collection at this URL:

`/sites/SiteCollectionName/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList`

In SharePoint on-prem there is an hourly (by default) Taxonomy Update Scheduler timer job that updates term changes on each site collection. In SPO we cannot run the timer job at our wish.

Reference: https://joannecklein.com/2018/11/26/changing-managed-metadata-values-in-sharepoint-online/

You can contact MS support team for more information.